# Algorithm Efficiency - Is partially unrolling a loop effective if it requires more comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, micro-optimization

How to judge if putting two extra assignments in an iteration is expensive or setting a if condition to test another thing? here I elaborate. question is to generate and PRINT the first n terms of the Fibonacci sequence where n>=1. my implement in C was:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x=0,y=1,output=0,l,n;
    printf("Enter the number of terms you need of Fibonacci Sequence ? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    for (l=1;l<=n;l++)
    {
        output=output+x;
        x=y;
        y=output;
        printf("%d ",output);
    }
}
```

but the author of the book "how to solve it by computer" says it is inefficient since it uses two extra assignments for a single fibonacci number generated. he suggested:

```
a=0
b=1
loop: 
print a,b
a=a+b
b=a+b
```

I agree this is more efficient since it keeps a and b relevant all the time and one assignment generates one number. BUT it is printing or supplying two fibonacci numbers at a time. suppose question is to generate an odd number of terms, what would we do? author suggested put a test condition to check if n is an odd number. wouldn't we be losing the gains of reducing number of assignments by adding an if test in every iteration?

Comment: Define "efficient". It has no effect on asymptotic complexity, may very wellmakes *no* difference *at all* when using an optimizing compiler, and even if there's a difference it will be really tiny and dwarfed by (as in, ten thousand times smaller than) the I/O overhead.

Comment: The only way to tell if it is "expensive" is by profiling both versions.

Comment: What might make a measurable difference is that it allows to print two numbers in one print statement. As @delnan said, the cost of the extra variable (if the compiler doesn't optimise that away) and the assignments (also checks) are minuscule compared to the I/O cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first advice echoes the others:  Strive first for clean, clear code, then optimize where you know there is a performance issue.   (It's hard to imagine a time-critical fibonacci sequencer...)

However, speaking as someone who does work on systems where microseconds matter, there is a simple solution to the question you ask:   Do the "if odd" test only once, not inside the loop.

The general pattern for loop unrolling is

```
  create X repetitions of the loop logic.
  divide N by X.
  execute the loop N/X times.
  handle the N%X remaining items.
```

For your specific case:

```
a=0;
b=1;
nLoops = n/2;
while (nloops-- > 0) {
  print a,b;
  a=a+b;
  b=a+b;
}
if (isOdd(n)) {
  print a; 
}
```

*(Note also that N/2 and isOdd are trivially implemented and extremely fast on a binary computer.)*

Answer (score 5):

I consider it very bad advice from the author to even bring this up in a book targeted at beginning programmers. (**Edit**: In all fairness, the book was originally published in 1982, a time when programming was generally much more low-level than it is now.)

99.9% of code does not need to be optimized. Especially in code like this that mixes extremely cheap operations (arithmetic on integers) with very expensive operations (I/O), it's a complete waste of time to optimize the cheap part.

Micro-optimizations like this should only be considered in time-critical code when it is necessary to squeeze every bit of performance out of your hardware.

When you do need it, the only way to know which of several options performs best is to *measure*. Even then, the results may change with different processors, platforms, memory configurations...

Answer (score 3):

Without commenting on your actual code: As you are learning to program, keep in mind that minor efficiency improvements that make code harder to read are not worth it. At least, they aren't until profiling of a production application reveals that it would be worth it.

Write code that can be read by humans; it will make your life much easier and keep maintenance programmers from cursing the name of you and your offspring.